# PostgreSQL: Get date and time from unix string format field

Tags: string, postgresql, date, epoch

I have such a query:

```
select
(featuremap ->> 'column.time:value')
from db.table;
```

This returns the unix timestamp as a string value. I tried several things:
E.g.:

```
select
extract(epoch from(featuremap ->> 'column.time:value'))
from db.table;
```

Which returns this error: `ERROR:  function pg_catalog.date_part(unknown, text) does not exist`

And:

```
select
to_timestamp(featuremap ->> 'column.time:value')
from db.table;
```

which returns this error: `ERROR:  function to_timestamp(text) does not exist`

What do I have to do in this case in order to get the date and time from the unix timestamp string/text field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [to_timestamp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) with a single epoch argument. Since the original type of the argument is `text` it needs to be first cast to a numeric type.

```sql
select
to_timestamp((featuremap ->> 'column.time:value')::double precision)
from db.table;
```